# Overwrites file even when I use: open("file", "a")

Tags: python

I'm trying to log the results of the last requests in a file. My problem is, that even when I use: "open("result.txt", "a")" the whole document gets overwritten. Does somebody know what the problem is?

That's my code:

```
def output(endpoint, code=None):
result = "result.txt"

if os.path.exists(result):
    os.remove(result)

f = open(result, "a")     
if code == 200:
    print("URL / IP = https://" + endpoint + " | Status: \033[92m" + "OK" + "\033[0m")
    f.write("URL / IP = https://" + endpoint + " | Status: OK" + "\n")
elif code == None:
    print("URL / IP = https://" + endpoint + " | Status: \033[91m" + "NOT OK" + "\033[0m")
    f.write("URL / IP = https://" + endpoint + " | Status: NOT OK" + "\n")
else:
    print("URL / IP = https://" + endpoint + " | Status: \033[91m" + code + " | NOT OK" + "\033[0m")
    f.write("URL / IP = https://" + endpoint + " | Status: " + code + " | NOT OK" + "\n")
f.close()
```

Best regards

Comment: Because you are explicitly deleting the file if it already exists.

Comment: If I may: ‍♂️‍♀️

Comment: Why is this question closed as Need Debugging details?

Comment: @Daemon Meh… because we cannot see any divergence between the presented code and the *desired behaviour*…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're literally deleting the file if it exists

```
if os.path.exists(result):
    os.remove(result)
```

remove that section.